# Several exchange accounts on one device

Tags: email, exchange

I'm thinking about replacing an iPhone with Android device, but before I do that I'd like to know which versions of Android support multiple Exchange accounts? Are all main features (Mail/Calendar/Contacts) supported when several accounts are set up?

Comment: I'd test it, but I don't have another Exchange account to connect to. I'm pretty sure it does though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Android 2.0 Exchange support was added and this included multiple exchange accounts.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0-highlights.html

The highlights there mention "Handset manufacturers can choose whether to include Exchange support in their devices." But all the the higher end devises (Galaxy S, Nexus One, HTC Desire etc) will most certainly support it.

Comment: Watch out - even when the Android version supports (multiple) Exchange accounts, device makers can cripple this functionality.  For example, in some HTC phones with the HTC Sense UI, HTC's email app only supports one Exchange account, even when multiple are supported by the underlying exchange version.

Comment: Worst case senario, there are 3rd party email clients for Android which will enable this facility if the devise makers have crippled it. For example https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qs.enhancedemail

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at least on 2.1+.  I do have the Samung TouchWiz UI though, and the email app is subtly different.  I would expect it to be the same in this regard however.  Note that the Email app is terrible, though, and may not otherwise behave how you want.  I recommend a third-party app or forwarding your email to Gmail.